# Getting an error calling Hasura Insert, "type citext does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I have an existing Hasura instance that uses Postgres 12 and Hasura 2.2.0. It has a schema called hauth_catalog and in that schema there is a table called users. This table has an email field that uses the citext extension type. I checked using Pgadmin that this extension type exists in the same schema. And this table is already existing and has data in it.

Please note I am able to insert directly into Postgres using Pgadmin without error.

When I try to make an insert call using the Hasura schema based api or the graphql api I get the error in the title. Here's the related code using the schema style but again either one fails:

```
export const getQuery = record => ({
  type: "insert",
  args: {
    schema: "hauth_catalog",
    table: "users",
    objects: [record]
  }
});

const headers = {} as any;
  if (DATA_API_TOKEN && DATA_API_TOKEN !== "undefined") {
    headers["X-Hasura-Admin-Secret"] = DATA_API_TOKEN;
  }

  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: DATA_API_URL, // path to Hasura
    headers,
    data: query
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

citext is not supported by Hasura at the moment. Check out the [list of supported data types](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/postgresql-types/)

Comment: This is not true, I've been using citext with Hasura for the past year with no issues. It just effectively gets mapped to a string for the purposes of interacting with the backend